# How to increase the frequency of a water wave?

Tags: frequency, piezoelectric

I am working on a piezoelectric device in a sea wall. Piezoelectrics take mechanical loading (like being squeezed) and can output an electrical signal. Unfortunately piezoelectric's don't work well in low frequency conditions, which is what the ocean current/waves are. Can you think of any designs or ways to increase the frequency at which the piezoelectric is being loaded (i.e. how much the water is hitting it).

Thanks!

Comment: No answer to the question, but I have worked with  piezo bimorph bending strips to cause some motion in water at frequencies around 100 Hz. That might work the other way around too.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way I know of to do this, but the basic problem you have here is you have a low-impedance source (water waves) driving a high-impedance sensor and the power transfer is therefore going to be extremely poor- as you have noticed.

You therefore need a *transformer* to match the source with the load. In your case this could take the form of a float or paddle on the end of a lever arm that has the piezo sensor near its fulcrum, so that when the wave action pushes on the end of the arm, the sensor gets pinched between the lever and a hard place. This will actuate the sensor with more force and furnish you with a larger signal.

Comment: Thanks so much! I figured it was something like that but was hoping there was something else I was missing.